# How to return exception message with bad request status from webflux app

Tags: exception, spring-webflux, bad-request

Could you please give me an advice, what is the proper way to return `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` from webflux handler?

Here's the code, it seems to work properly, exception message returns as needed, but the response status is 200, while needed to be 400. Please note, that returning media type is `TEXT_EVENT_STREAM` -

```
@Component
public class ResolveHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> resolve(ServerRequest request) {
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .body(
                        new ResultsFluxer(
                            Integer.valueOf(request.queryParam("numberOfIterations").orElse("0")),
                            request.queryParam("function1").orElse(""),
                            request.queryParam("function2").orElse(""),
                            orderingType
                        )
                        .getResult()
                        .onErrorResume(e -> Flux.just(e.getMessage()))
                        , Flux.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling

Comment: I've read this, and error handling in my example works fine, cause on error it returns error message, just as planned. The question is: how can i effect the serverresponse from it's body (which is Flux)? I mean, if an error occurs in the body of Response, how do i change response status? Maybe i miss something

Comment: `.onErrorResume(e -> Flux.just(e.getMessage()))` here you are basically just saying take the error message, putting it in a flux and return it to the client. Så you are not in any way aborting the subscripition. Think of it like the assembly belt analogy. Someone subscribes, you return data, data, data, data then something goes wrong, what you do is take the error msg wrap it in data and return it and then you resume the regular data feed.

Comment: Since you want to return a REST error code, what you need to do you need to break the subscription to return an error code. This is done by instead of return a `Flux.just(e.getMessage)` *because here you are basically just saying "return a regular flux with this error msg" you need to return a `Flux.error` containing for instans a `ResponseStatusException` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.0/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html

but remember returning a exception is a terminal event that will break the subscription from the client.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-exception-handler

Comment: but there are several ways of handling exceptions https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-controller-exceptions